# Plot line chart for each row in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 20 columns and I used groupby on two columns and then I got this.

```
data.groupby(['id','date']).count()['dx'].iplot()

 id     date                    
 K01   2019-04-04 12:47:31.610    1
       2019-04-05 13:52:50.923    1
       2019-04-06 11:29:55.357    1
       2019-04-07 19:08:17.370    1
       2019-04-08 10:58:02.710    1
       2019-04-08 12:07:15.477    1
       2019-04-08 15:23:48.850    1
                                 ..
 K5    2019-06-24 21:06:50.563    1
       2019-06-25 17:07:49.880    1
       2019-06-25 19:44:18.720    1
       2019-06-26 05:46:45.343    1

Name: id, Length: 99466, dtype: int64
```

I have multiple id's and as you can see the length is too much. 
how do i plot graph for each id?
with date as x axis and count as y axis and id as the title?

I tried using iplot -  plotly and it turns out to be a blunder.

[image]

What other type of plot I can use to portray all id ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What did `data.groupby(['id','date']).count()['dx'].plot()` do for example?

Comment: Also i tried matplotlb, that also does not serve the purpose either'

Comment: you need to add the code you used for the plot. Also, did you try the code I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: Similar graph appears. just same as the iplot one ive added

Comment: you need to include the code used to generate the plot. Are you using a histogram?

Comment: iplot() does it automatically. Iplot() is for plotly.

Comment: I need a line chart actually

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a dataframe in which each column is the series that you want to plot.

```
plt.tight_layout()
data.groupby(['id','date']).count()['dx'].unstack('id', fill_value=0).plot()
```

In this case, each series is indexed by the id (e.g. "K01", "K5") so you just have to unstack the dataframe and plot it.

However, if the number of ids is too large, the plot could be hard to read. Using the plotting option `subplots=True` might help; otherwise, I would consider another kind of graph.